# 3rd degree polynomial & solving for $f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am trying to find a closed form solution for $f$ in the following equation:

$0 = \mu - f (\mu^2 + \sigma^2) + f^2\lambda_3 - f^3\lambda_4$

This is an excerpt from the following SSRN paper which derives the Kelly Criterion to include the 3rd and 4th moments (which are typically omitted from the common $\mu/\sigma^2$ derivation. Derivation for the solution is not provided.

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2956161

Please help!

Comment: watch again what you wrote, there's a $f^{3}\lambda_{3}-f^{3}\lambda_{3}$ which of course simplifies the computation.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is in the form where you can apply Cardano's formula. You can write:
$$t^{3}+pt+q=0$$
Where we applied a change of variable of the form:
$$f=t+\frac{\lambda_{3}}{3\lambda_{4}}$$
Once you do so, the term of degree $2$ will disappear, so that you can proceed.
Now you want to compute:
$$\Delta=\Big(\frac{q}{2}\Big)^{2}+\Big(\frac{p}{3}\Big)^{3}$$
The first solution is:
$$u=\Big(-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\Delta} \Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\Big(-\frac{q}{2}-\sqrt{\Delta} \Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
By First solution I mean the one you derive directly from this formula. If $\Delta>0$ then it will give you a real value, thus by dividing by $(f-u)$ you will find the other $2$ solutions (which can be complex or not).

If $\Delta<0$ then the same formula actually holds, but it will give you $2$ conjugated complex numbers, and it requires you to know how to handle complex roots.

Notice this is nothing original by me, it is how historically cubic equations were solved. To see documentation on it, you can search for Cardano's Formula.

Comment: So basically we transform it into a depressed cubic to easily get p and q.  From there, our first root is ‘u’ consisting of variables p, q, and Δ, where p and q have already been solved for, and Δ is simply a function of p and q.  That’s our first of the 3 roots (assuming it gives us a real value, then this is probably the ‘applied’ solution I am looking for.

The other 2 roots are found using complex #s and probably wouldn’t have too much relevance in an applied setting, I assume.

Is my understanding correct?  Also, what procedure did you use to define Δ?

Comment: That is the idea indeed. I just noticed now that in the polynomial there's a term of degree $2$, so I'm going to adjust the final answer